# Update embedded data on referenced data update

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am building a Meteor application and am currently creating the publications and coming up against what seems like a common design quandary around related vs embedded documents.  My data model (simplified) has `Bookings`, each of which have a related `Client` and a related `Service`.  In order to optimise the speed of retrieving a collection I am embedding the key fields of a `Client` and `Service` in the `Booking`, and also linking to the ID - my Booking model has the following structure:

```
export interface Booking extends CollectionObject {
  client_name: string;
  service_name: string;
  client_id: string;
  service_id: string;
  bookingDate: Date;
  duration: number;
  price: number;
}
```

In this model, `client_id` and `service_id` are references to the linked documents and `client_name` / `service_name` are embedded as they are used when displaying a list of bookings.

This all seems fine to me however the missing part of the puzzle is keeping this embedded data up to date.  If a user in a separate part of the system updates a service (which would be a reactive collection) then I need this to trigger an update of the service_name to any bookings with the corresponding service ID.  Is there an event I should subscribe to for this or am I able to?  Client side, I have a form which allows the user to add / edit a Service which simply uses the insert or update method on the MongoObservable collection - the OOP part of me feels like this needs to be overridden in the server code to also then update the related data or am I completely going about this the wrong way?

Is this all irrelevant and shoudl I actually just use https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite and return collections of related documents (it just feels like it would harm performance in a production environment when returning several hundred bookings at once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use a lot of the "foreign key" concept as you're describing, and do de-normalize data across collection as you're doing with the service name. i do this explicitly to avoid extra lookups / publishes.

i use 2 strategies to keep things up to date. the first is done when the source data is saved, say in a Meteor method call. i'll update the de-normalized data on the spot, touching the other collection(s). i would do all this in a "high read, low write" scenario.

the other strategy is to use collection hooks to fire when the source collection is updated. i use this package: matb33:collection-hooks

conceptually, it's similar to the first, but the hook into knowing when to do it is different.

an example we're using in the current app i'm working on: we have a news feed with comments. news items and comments are in separate collections, and each record the comment collection has the id of the associated news item.

we keep a running comment count associated with the news item itself. whenever a comment is added or removed, we increment/decrement the count and update the news item right away.